# I can't enable slick slider autoplay

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

I am trying to setup a blog for a friend and it has prebuild slick slider.
I am really not good with Html and Javascript and i was trying to setup autoplay for the slider alla fternoon.

Where should i add a class? How should i setup javascript? I really dont know what i should do in order autoplay to be enabled. It is default false. Please explain to me

Slick classes defined are :

````
/* slicknav */
/*
Mobile Menu Core Style
*/
.slicknav_btn { position: relative; display: block; vertical-align: middle; float: left; padding: 0.438em 0.625em 0.438em 0.625em; line-height: 1.125em; cursor: pointer; }
.slicknav_menu  .slicknav_menutxt { display: block; line-height: 1.188em; float: left; }
.slicknav_menu .slicknav_icon { float: left; padding:3px;}
.slicknav_menu .slicknav_no-text { margin: 0 }
.slicknav_menu .slicknav_icon-bar { display: block; width: 1.125em; height: 0.125em; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); }
.slicknav_btn .slicknav_icon-bar + .slicknav_icon-bar { margin-top: 0.188em }
.slicknav_nav { clear: both }
.slicknav_nav ul,
.slicknav_nav li { display: block ;line-height: 20px;}
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_arrow { font-size: 0.8em; margin: 0 0 0 0.4em; }
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_item { cursor: pointer; }
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_row { display: block; }
.slicknav_nav a { display: block }
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_item a,
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_parent-link a { display: inline }
.slicknav_menu:before,
.slicknav_menu:after { content: " "; display: table; }
.slicknav_menu:after { clear: both }
/* IE6/7 support */
.slicknav_menu { *zoom: 1 }
/*
User Default Style
Change the following styles to modify the appearance of the menu.
*/
.slicknav_menu {
font-size:16px;
}
/* Button */
.slicknav_btn {
margin: 3px;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

.slicknav_menu>a {
    border: 1px solid #eee; background: #fff;

}

/* Button Text */
.slicknav_menu  .slicknav_menutxt {
color: #000;
font-weight: bold;
float:right;
}
/* Button Lines */
.slicknav_menu .slicknav_icon-bar {
background-color: #fff;
}
.slicknav_menu {

padding:0px;    
}
.slicknav_nav {
color:#fff;
background:#000;
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-size:0.875em;
}
.slicknav_nav, .slicknav_nav ul {
list-style: none;
overflow:hidden;
}
.slicknav_nav ul {
padding:0;
margin:0 0 0 20px;
}
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_row {
padding:5px 10px;
margin:2px 5px;
}
.slicknav_nav a{
padding:5px 10px;
margin:2px 5px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#fff;
}
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_item a,
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_parent-link a {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_row:hover {
background:#ccc;
color:#fff;
}
.slicknav_nav a:hover{
background:#ccc;
color:#222;
}
.slicknav_nav .slicknav_txtnode {
margin-left:15px;
}
/* slicknav */
.slicknav_menu {
display:none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 890px) {
/* #masthead is the original menu */
#navtop {
display:none;
}
.slicknav_menu {
display:block;
}
}```



and 

    /* Slider */
    .slick-slider
    {
        position: relative;
    margin-bottom:0;
        display: block;
        box-sizing: border-box;

        -webkit-user-select: none;
           -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
                user-select: none;

        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
            touch-action: pan-y;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;odd-pager
    }

    .slick-list
    {
        position: relative;

        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;

        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }


    .slick-list:focus
    {
        outline: none;
    }
    .slick-list.dragging
    {
        cursor: pointer;
        cursor: hand;
    }

    .slick-slider .slick-track,
    .slick-slider .slick-list
    {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
           -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
             -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
                transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }

    .slick-track
    {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;

        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    .slick-track:before,
    .slick-track:after
    {
        display: table;

        content: '';
    }
    .slick-track:after
    {
        clear: both;
    }
    .slick-loading .slick-track
    {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .slick-slide
    {
        display: none;
        float: left;

        height: 100%;
        min-height: 1px;
    }
    [dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
    {
        float: right;
    }
    .slick-slide img
    {
        display: block;
    }
    .slick-slide.slick-loading img
    {
        display: none;
    }
    .slick-slide.dragging img
    {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    .slick-initialized .slick-slide
    {
        display: block;
    }
    .slick-loading .slick-slide
    {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .slick-vertical .slick-slide
    {
        display: block;

        height: auto;

        border: 1px solid transparent;
    }
    .slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
        display: none;
    }

    .slick-next{right:0px;}
    .slick-prev {

        margin-right: 8px;
    left:0px;
    }

    .slick-prev, .slick-next {
        top: 50%;
    z-index:999;
        width: 40px;

        height: 50px;
    }
    .slick-next:before {
        content: "";
    }
    .slick-prev:before {
        content: "";
    }

    .slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before{opacity:0;font-size:40px;transition:300ms;-o-transition:300ms;-moz-transition:300ms;-webkit-transition:300ms;}



    .slick-prev:before {
        color: #fff;text-align: center;
        display: block;
        line-height: 0;
    }

    .slick-next:before {
        color: #fff;text-align: center;
        display: block;
        line-height: 0;
    }

    .slickslider .item-wrap-inner{position:relative;}

    .slickslider .item-info {
            width:100%;font-size: 12px;

    }
    .slickslider .item{position:relative;}
    .slickslider
     .item-image {
        background: #000;
    }

    .slickslider .item-image a {
        opacity: .7!important;
    }
    .itemtopinfo {
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        width: 55%;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    }
    .slickslider .item-info {
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
````

Comment: It's a setting in the JavaScript initialization. Could you add the JavaScript part where Slick is used?

Comment: Yes, this should have nothing to do with the CSS classes listed. Those deal with the look and feel not the functionality. Also, could you link to the slider you've implemented?

Comment: @ps138 Where is your full code?

Answer (score 1):

Slick Slider has the `autoplay` option, which when set to `true` will play automatically. With the `autoplaySpeed` option you can set the interval of the autoplay function in **milliseconds**.
Add both the `autoplay: true` and `autoplaySpeed: 2000` to your initialization in your JavaScript file.

```
$('.the-slider-class').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
});
```

Otherwise, if you JavaScript file cannot be changed or for any other reason, you can edit the HTML of the slider element and add a `data-attribute` to the element. The value of the `data-attribute` is a JSON string with the same settings as your JavaScript counterpart. See example below.

```
<div class="the-slider-class" data-slick='{"autoplay": true, "autoplaySpeed": 2000}'>
  ...
</div>
```

Either should do the trick.

If you currently have other settings that you use, then make sure that you incorporate those as well in your JavaScript or HTML.

Look for all the options at the [documentation and examples](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) of Slick Slider.